# error 1004 in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I got some code for selecting the nearest value to the user value that is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim col As Integer 
col = Me.TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SMALL($A$1:$EN$1,COUNTIF($A$1:$EN$1,""<" & col & """)+1)"
End Sub
```

But i am getting RUNTIME ERROR 1004
 anybody help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoke the R1C1-style formula property, but supply an A1-style formula. Try this instead:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SMALL($A$1:$EN$1,COUNTIF($A$1:$EN$1,""<" & col & """)+1)"
```

i.e. `ActiveCell.Formula` instead of `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: May I know how to add this value to variable

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN: which value? The value in ActiveCell after you have added the formula? That would be `someVar = ActiveCell.Value`.

Comment: Yes stephan cant we add value directly to variable without adding the value to activecell I mean 

varsome = "=SMALL($A$1:$EN$1,COUNTIF($A$1:$EN$1,""<" & col & """)+1)"

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN: this is possible, but a little complicated (hence, it might be confusing in a comment). Let me try: 1) set the relevant range: `Set rng = Range("$A$1:$EN$1")` 2) get the COUNTIF number: `belowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "<" & col) + 1` 3) Finally get the result: `someVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(rng, belowNum)`. This is totally untested. Hope it helps.

Comment: hello stephan the code which u hav given is working correctly but can u please tell me how that small() function works

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN: I don't think I can explain it much better than the online help. `SMALL(array, k)` returns the `k`-th smallest value in a data set `array`.